# background transition dont work, none to img, css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

enter code here

hi guys, i want to make a smooth transition, with 0.4 5s, it goes from bg none to a bg image, should have a way...

im trying the following:

```
`


>.content {  /*class in div id topcontent */
>>position: relative;

>>padding-top: 1150px;

>>width: 900px;
>>margin: 0px auto 0px auto;

>>z-index:1;

>>-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;  
>>transition: all 0.9s ease;

>}

>.gobg { /* the bg class */
>>background: url(../images/gradientwhitelow.png) center repeat-y;

>>-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;  

>>transition: all 0.9s ease;

>}

and js


><script>
>>if ($(window).scrollTop() > 690){
        $("#topcontent").toggleClass( "gobg", true );
>>}</script>
```

`

any tips?

thanks!

i corrected the js, worng code

Comment: What are the `>>` for in your CSS code? And can we have some HTML?

Answer (score 0):

the `background-image` property is not animatable: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image

According to the specifications, color **is** animatable, however. So you may want to try two divs: one has your background image, and the one on top of it animates from `background-color: somecolor` to `background-color: transparent`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this table of animatable properties...

http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/#background-image

you'll note that background-image has that little subscript 2.  Check out that part in the bottom and you read:

> "While CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3 Editor’s Draft says
>   “Animatable: no” for background-image at the time of writing, support
>   for crossfading images in CSS appeared in Chrome 19 Canary. Until
>   widespread support arrives this can be faked via image sprites and
>   background-position or opacity. To animate gradients they must be the
>   same type."